# Is there any trick to change the event fire order of mouseenter and mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dom-events

I am relatively new to d3. I have events setup on my svg circles drawn using d3. These circles can have child circles and can also intersect. So to prevent bubbled events I used mouseenter but used mouseout to trigger events from childs as well.

The event fire order according to my observation is:

1. mouseenter
2. mouseover
3. mouseout
4. mouseleave

Is there any trick to change this event fire order?

Comment: You could instead of using different events also prevent bubbling by using `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Yes I can, but I am just asking out of curiosity if the order can be changed neatly

Comment: No. You'd have to change the way it's implemented in the browser (and would break about half the internet in the process).

Comment: Ah well that would be bad, thank you